# Alternative to out variables

Tags: c#

I need to include `double.TryParse(wordConf, out double wordConfDouble);` in a script, but I get a `feature out variable declaration is not available in c# 6` error message. Searching for it on Google, I can only see solutions for upgrading to `C# 7` (which I am not allowed to do so in this project) so I wonder if someone could help me write an equivalent to this line that would work in any C# compiler.

Comment: Just declare the variable before using it in `TryParse`. `double wordConfDouble; double.TryParse(wordConf, out wordConfDouble);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to inline declare a type for out-parameters.

Replace:

```
double.TryParse(wordConf, out double wordConfDouble);
```

With:

```
double wordConfDouble;
double.TryParse(wordConf, out wordConfDouble);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just the inline declaration which is not supported in < `C#7.0`. Change your code to

```
double wordConfDouble;
double.TryParse(wordConf, out wordConfDouble);
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#out-variables

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the reference. I had to mark the previous post as answer though, as it was posted just beforehand, but I do appreciate your reply.